# Objective-C: First item of NSArray sometimes is missing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

I have and NSArray with 5 string elements, populating an UITableView of my iPhone App.

Everything works fine, but sometimes the first string of my array is missing and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
arrayList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"My First String", 
                                              @"My Second String",
                                              @"My Third String",
                                              @"My Forth String",
                                              @"My Fifth Sring",
                                              nil];
```

The element that sometimes just doesn't show up is **My First String**

Actually I'm using this sample code from Cocoa With Love. Thanks guys for helping me!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

#if USE_CUSTOM_DRAWING
    const NSInteger TOP_LABEL_TAG = 1001;
//  const NSInteger BOTTOM_LABEL_TAG = 1002;
    UILabel *topLabel;
//  UILabel *bottomLabel;
#endif

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    //
    // Create the cell.
    //
    cell =
    [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
      initWithFrame:CGRectZero
      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
     autorelease];

#if USE_CUSTOM_DRAWING

    UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    cell.accessoryView =
    [[[UIImageView alloc]
      initWithImage:indicatorImage]
     autorelease];

    const CGFloat LABEL_HEIGHT = 22;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

    //
    // Create the label for the top row of text
    //
    topLabel =
    [[[UILabel alloc]
      initWithFrame:
      CGRectMake(
                 image.size.width + 2.0 * cell.indentationWidth,
                 0.5 * (aTableView.rowHeight - 1.3 * LABEL_HEIGHT),
                 aTableView.bounds.size.width -
                 image.size.width - 4.0 * cell.indentationWidth
                 - indicatorImage.size.width,
                 LABEL_HEIGHT)]
     autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:topLabel];

    //
    // Configure the properties for the text that are the same on every row
    //
    topLabel.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    topLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


     topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
     topLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];


    topLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
    topLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 

    /*

    //
    // Create the label for the bottom row of text
    //
    bottomLabel =
    [[[UILabel alloc]
      initWithFrame:
      CGRectMake(
                 image.size.width + 2.0 * cell.indentationWidth,
                 0.5 * (aTableView.rowHeight - 2 * LABEL_HEIGHT) + LABEL_HEIGHT,
                 aTableView.bounds.size.width -
                 image.size.width - 4.0 * cell.indentationWidth
                 - indicatorImage.size.width,
                 LABEL_HEIGHT)]
     autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:bottomLabel];

    //
    // Configure the properties for the text that are the same on every row
    //
    bottomLabel.tag = BOTTOM_LABEL_TAG;
    bottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    bottomLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    bottomLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    bottomLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize] - 2];

    */



    //
    // Create a background image view.
    //
    cell.backgroundView =
    [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView =
    [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif
}

#if USE_CUSTOM_DRAWING
else
{
    topLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:TOP_LABEL_TAG];
//  bottomLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:BOTTOM_LABEL_TAG];
}

topLabel.text = [arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
//bottomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some other information.", [indexPath row]];

//  [cell LabelText:[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


//
// Set the background and selected background images for the text.
// Since we will round the corners at the top and bottom of sections, we
// need to conditionally choose the images based on the row index and the
// number of rows in the section.
//
UIImage *rowBackground;
UIImage *selectionBackground;
NSInteger sectionRows = [aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (row == 0 && row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected_copy.png"];
}
else if (row == 0)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRowSelected_copy.png"];
}
else if (row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRowSelected_copy.png"];
}
else
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelected_copy.png"];
}
((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;



if (row == 0)
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
}
else if (row == 1)
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
}
else if (row == 2)
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];
}

else if (row == 3)
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4.png"];
}

else if (row == 4)
{
    cell.imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic5.png"];
}

#else

[cell LabelText:[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

//cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell at row %ld.", [indexPath row]];
#endif

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is the first element an empty string? How do you set the elements in the array?

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: The moat obvious (though hardly certain) answer would be that sometimes your code fails to add the object, but we can't tell you anything specific since all you've given us is a vague outline. Objects do not simply go "missing" from arrays.

Comment: I've just included my code above. Thanks!

Comment: @Winston, you should also post the source code for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: From what you've included, the only way a string declared in that way would fail to be added would be due to memory allocation or memory corruption issues. But that's astronomically improbable. There has to be more about what happens with @"My First String" that you're not saying. Is it pulled in as a string constant from a different file? Is it read out of a user defaults dictionary? I find it hard to believe a string declared inline with the array initialiser would simply not exist sometimes.

Comment: Without seeing more, the only other thing I can think of is you are sometimes accessing / displaying index 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4

Comment: You haven't shown enough code, yet.  The problem is not w/that line of code. If *that* didn't work, your phone & mac wouldn't boot.

Comment: I've included the code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are probably having is accessing object 1 as index 1... Arrays in Objective-C are the same as most other C structured languages. Indexed starting at 0.

Put this code in.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayList count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Item %d = %@", i, [arrayList objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Chances are good that this works fine.

If that is not the case the I would recommend restoring your iphone to factory default as either the operating system is malfunctioning, or you have other rogue processes that are corrupting memory.

To debug the code above. As you are grabbing the items out of the array I would put in an NSLog()

```
NSString *objectAtIndex = [arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Row: %d, Object: %@, Count: %d",indexPath.row, objectAtIndex, [arrayList count]);
[cell LabelText:[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm considering your code and I've put the one I'm using edited above.

Comment: I am wondering if perhaps your table is not requesting the first item before you populate the array ?

Comment: Maybe. How do I make sure that doesnt happen? Thanks.

Comment: Debug the app with the logs and see if it is occuring. You should get some good info from the NSLog Command I put up. Your line is [cell LabelText:[arrayList objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row]]; and the others I put up will show you what is in the variables when they are about to set the label text.. Look into that and see if that is what is happening. If that is happening, then you will have to initialize the array sooner. if not then it could be some other fluke. but you can see what is going on if you print out to the log.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow morning and will let you know the results. Once again thanks for helping me.

Comment: Hi Jason. Your code helped me debugging my program. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Are you doing something similar to this for populating table view

Answer (score -2):

```
NSMutableArray *ArrayList=[[NSMutableArray   alloc]initWithObjects: @"My First String", 
                                              @"My Second String",
                                              @"My Third String",
                                              @"My Forth String",
                                              @"My Fifth Sring",
                                              nil];
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would this fix anything?